# What do I need to know before upgrading to a larger data drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, sata, data-transfer

I'm running Windows 7, and am swapping out my current 1TB SATA HDD for a 2TB one, and *want to be sure that I'm following best practices and generally doing things in the smartest, most efficient way that I can*.

This is a pure data drive that contains only the Windows `Users` folder on it, so my plan of action is:

- Connect the new drive to the computer via SATA
- Copy the entirety of the `Users` folder over to the new drive in the usual way (or perhaps using something like Robocopy or Clonezilla)
- Reassign the new drive with the current drive's letter to avoid breaking paths

Are there any gotchas that I should be aware of before going about this process, on either the hardware or OS side? For example, are there parts of the Users folder that I don't need to copy, or absolutely shouldn't?

Comment: If you have used `D:\ ` as `Users`-folder, why shouldn't the new `D:\ `-drive work the same way? Also, closely related: https://superuser.com/questions/1218965/upgrading-secondary-hdd-copy-paste-sufficient/1218990#1218990

Comment: If you do it with Clonezilla I assume you'd want to expand the restored partition to a larger size than it is from the source 1 TB drive when the backup occurs. Does CloneZilla allow file-level backups? I've only done whole disk or partition image backups with CZ and it's been a while too. The plan is to have one large 2 TB partition for the `/Users` data?

Comment: @flolilolilo - Thanks for the link, I'll have a read. I'm banking on it working the same way, but I just want to be sure there are no surprises, both after the copy and during the copying process itself.

Comment: @TheFurryITSnuggleBuddy Good shout, I didn't realise CZ was exclusively an image cloning tool similar to dd rather than just a copying tool. Yeah, that's the plan, I don't really see any reason to split it up into different partitions.

Comment: Well...if you have **all** of the user-files on the HDD (including AppData,..), then it might be a problem if some program is accessing that while copying. Will it be a problem? I wouldn't think so. If that would be a problem, than I'd wonder how you got it working in the first place.

Comment: I also want to be sure that the way I'm doing things is the best way to do so - would running from a liveCD for example, be faster?

Comment: Right. . .  because if you currently already have a 1 TB drive and partition, then you could actually just add a separate physical disk (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) to get another partition so that makes sense you'd want to increase the partition you are cloning over. You might shoot for the image solution if you can coordinate the downtime or simply test it out with the new 2 TB drive as you actually have nothing to loose other than a 2 TB HD you have to wipe and try another method with the next time other than downtime in this environment for backup and restore operations.

Comment: I say if you can coordinate downtime try with CZ since you can be offline and booted to CZ and take the backup image of the partition and immediately take out that (1 TB) drive and set it to the side, put in the 2 TB drive, boot to CZ, push the image to it, boot up in Windows, expand the disk... done.

Comment: As long as it's 2 TB or less, I think you'll be fine with Windows 7: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2581408/windows-support-for-hard-disks-that-are-larger-than-2-tb . . .

Comment: Its worth considering *how* you set the user folders to a seperate folder, since if memory serves, this is a slightly non standard setup. Its also worth considering if you're fine running the drives side by side temporarily.

Comment: It's been a few years but I followed the longer method described here, which is the most complete way to do the transfer there was at the time, and looks like it still is: http://serverfault.com/a/8201/329607. And what would need the drives side-by-side be in the event of?

Comment: Sorry, @JourneymanGeek, forgot to notify you.

Answer (score 2):

The method least likely to cause problems would be to perform an 1) **off-line** 2) **bit-for-bit** copy of the drive using a tool such as [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php). This will ensure a seamless transition where the *only* thing that changes is the underlying storage device.

After performing the clone, disconnect the old drive and replace it with the new one, boot Windows, and use Disk Manager to expand the volume to fill the new disk.

Advantages of this method include:

- Retention of any shadow copies stored on the volume
- Zero data loss from issues that may occur if the copy is performed while Windows is running
- Preservation of all NTFS permissions
- Use of same disk signature for the volume on the new disk
- Retention of any page file stored on the disk
- Your original drive can be used as a pristine backup in case your new drive turns out to be a lemon-flavored time bomb
- Preservation of any Recycle Bin contents
- And probably some others I'll think of later

---

#### Why an offline copy is easier than performing the copy while Windows is running

Since it's tempting to connect the new drive and perform the copy operation while Windows is booting, let's consider some possible drawbacks of this method:

1. **You won't be able to copy *everything* in the `\Users\` folder structure.** Even if you use a tool like RoboCopy, you'll encounter files that A) won't copy, or B) if they do copy, they won't contain changes still cached in RAM. The best example would be the User portion of the Registry of the currently logged on user. *(You *might* be able to work around this by creating a shadow copy of the disk, then copying the data out of the shadow copy...)*
2. **You may have trouble assigning the drive letter of the old disk to the new one.**

   - If you try to remove the drive letter while the old drive is attached, Windows won't let you because portions of the logged on user's account are stored there.
   - If you shut down the computer and pull the old drive, Windows may not boot properly because it can't find any valid user profiles. *(I've not tried this, but it is possible Windows would log you in with a temporary user profile. If so, then you might get far enough to be able to assign the correct drive letter to the new disk.)*

Comment: I've actually been leaning more towards using Robocopy so I can continue using my computer and to avoid the extra steps of creating a bootable, booting into Clonezilla, and expanding the partition after. Imaging seems overkill to me for just a data drive, seeing that as far as I'm aware Robocopy can be configured to make a copy with all of the above advantages. The only real potential problem that I can see with RC is that it can't transfer open files, but during the transfer I only need the computer to browse the internet, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If you're logged in with one of the user profiles stored on this drive, there's going to be files open on it...notably the user portion of the Registry.

Comment: Further, after you're done with Robocopy, you'll have data on a *different* drive letter. You won't be able to change that while Windows is running...but if you pull the source drive Windows won't be able to load the user profiles on the drive, preventing you from booting Windows and changing the volume's drive letter back to what it needs to be.

Comment: With regards to the latter point, I did think about it, but [came across this](https://superuser.com/questions/645160/any-harm-in-swapping-sata-ports), which suggests that likely won't be an issue if I simply use the same SATA port, and may even prevent me from needing to reassign the drive letter after.

Comment: Regarding the first point, I didn't know that's how Robocopy worked. That would definitely be an issue, I may have to look into it more.

Comment: Windows doesn't track volume drive letters based on which hardware interface port the disk is connected to. I'm not sure how it's done (perhaps a volume GUID?), but I assure you on next boot the same drive letter will be assigned.